# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error while compiling and running in JDK 1.7

Tags: java, tomcat

There's nothing much to say except that this error appears even after uninstalling JDK 8

Prologue:

I got the same error in my server, and I've looked it up, and it says version 52 error is because the compilation is done in different java version and you are executing this in another server (52 indicating : You need to use java 8)

So the solutions I found out from SO is

1. Run the program in java 8 (Cannot do because it's a corporate server running on java 7)
2. Compile the program in java 7 ( Did it, changed the environment variables to java 8, tomcat still points to java 7)
3. People said you need to uninstall a java because there should not be two jdk existing in 1 system

So since I cannot do anything in server, I did the following things in my localhost
 1. Uninstalled jdk 8, installed jdk 7
 2. Changed env variables to 7
 3. now tomcat server shows JVM to be java 7
 4. Recompiled in java 7
 5. When I execute this, it says the unsupported major.minor version 52

These are my settings
[image]

[image]

And when I start tomcat from XAMPP[image]

Nothing is related to Java 8 and yet I get this error, Is this because JAVA 7 is old?

As suggested from the comments, here is the error file[image]

And the console response

[image]

Comment: `Is this because JAVA 7 is old?` -- Not really, this is because v52 bytecode is created with Java 8 and later.

Comment: Did you check bit version?

Comment: You must still have some Java 8 compilates in your classpath. Are you sure you have recompiled everything? I would delete the compiled artifacts and then recompile.

Comment: you need to clean an re-compile the code using java7

Comment: You haven't shown the precise error, which should (IIRC) tell you which class is failing to load properly.

Comment: What is your build process exactly? Do you use maven? If the build process is automated, it might be that the configuration of your build tool still points to a Java 8 installation.

Comment: Do you have any jars which is being used by your code and the jar was compiled using with Java 8 ?

Comment: wow, didn't expect lightning quick replies...Bit version is what is required, i.e java 7 for windows 10 64bit,  I did not recompile everything, just what the files that's being used, @JonSkeet, I will edit the answer and post the exact error, The error is for X file, I've recompiled X file in java 7, yet shows the same error, I am unclear about maven, I use xampp 3.2 and it has tomcat 7

Comment: "I did not recompile everything, just what the files that's being used" - not sure what you mean by that, but only doing a partial recompile sounds like a recipe for confusion to me.

Comment: There are redundant old files which have been replicated as new files(with new names) and are currently used instead of that, I've kept the old files for reference for new members

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue in gradle build after that i have removed my all java versions(1.7 and 1.8) and then reinstalled 1.7 version and gradle build was working fine.